# Error compiling a C project with tow source files (linux)

Tags: c, linux, gcc, clang

I was watching a tutorial on making a chess engine using the C programing language.
I did exactly like the guy who made the video did but When I try to compile I get this error:

```
gcc -o chessman main.c init.c
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc9FX3Yd.o: warning: relocation against `Sq120ToSq64' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccrqZ8lV.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to `Sq120ToSq64'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0xd2): undefined reference to `Sq64ToSq120'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc9FX3Yd.o: in function `InitSq120To64':
init.c:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `Sq120ToSq64'
/usr/bin/ld: init.c:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to `Sq64ToSq120'
/usr/bin/ld: init.c:(.text+0xb6): undefined reference to `Sq64ToSq120'
/usr/bin/ld: init.c:(.text+0xd0): undefined reference to `Sq120ToSq64'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:2: all] Error 1
```

Note: He was using windows and I use linux.

My project folder contain:

- main.c
- init.c
- defs.h
- makefile

#### This is my makefile:

```
all:
   gcc -o chessman main.c init.c
```

### main.c:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "defs.h"

int main()
{
  ...

                printf("%5d",Sq120ToSq64[index]);
```

#### defs.h:

```
#ifndef DEFS_H
#define DEFS_H

typedef unsigned long long U64; // 64 bit number represent the chess board's squares
...

/* GLOBALS */

extern int Sq120ToSq64[BRD_SQ_NUM];
extern int Sq64ToSq120[64];

/* FUNCTIONS */

extern void AllInit();

// init.c

#endif
```

#### init.c

```
// init.c
#include "defs.h"

extern int Sq120ToSq64[BRD_SQ_NUM];
extern int Sq64ToSq120[64];

void InitSq120To64(){
...

}
void AllInit(){
        InitSq120To64();
}
```

Comment: `extern int Sq120ToSq64[BRD_SQ_NUM];` is an explicit declaration of the variable `Sq120ToSq64`. To *define* the variable you shouldn't use the `extern` keyword.

Comment: But I want to use the variable in my main.c and init.c so it should be extern right?

Comment: In the *header* file yes. But not in the *source* file. Declare in header file, define in source file.

Comment: Declare it (with `extern`) in *one* header file, and define it (without `extern`) in *one* `.c` file.